# PyQt6 hide() and show() function not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

I am trying to hide a UI and then show one, but I can't get or `hide()` or `show()` to work.

My current code looks like this:

```py
import crys.main.ui.mainmenu as w
import crys.main.ui.editor as e
w.Window().hide()
self.ui.hide()
e.Window().show()
```

The editor I want to open

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

import crys.main.helper as h


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Booting editor...")

        self.setWindowTitle(h.translate("window.editor"))
        self.setFixedSize(100, 100)

        a = QLabel(self)
        a.setText("cool")

        self.setStyleSheet(h.get_theme())
```

and the main menu

```py
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, should_build_ui: bool = False):
        super().__init__()

        self.buttons = []

        self.setStyleSheet(h.get_theme())

        self.setWindowTitle(h.translate("window.main"))
        self.setFixedSize(960, 540)

        if should_build_ui:
            self.build_ui()
```

`self.ui` is dialog (QWidget), and the `w.Window()` is a main menu. I expected that `e.Window().show` the editor window would show, but it didn't. It does hide the `self.ui`.

Comment: `w.Window().show()` will just create an instance that is being *immediately* destroyed (do some research about garbage collection and variable scope). You probably have to create a persistent reference to an instance and call `show()` for it, but in order to be able to help you, you need to provide a valid [mre] for your first code, as right now that portion is insufficient and meaningless.